# Typesetting a matrix and its reduced row echelon matrix next to each other using `empheq`

Tags: matrices

I am trying to put these two matrices next to each other in the same `empheq` environment, separated by a comma and the space allotted by `\qquad \quad`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left = \empheqlbrack, right =\empheqrbrack]{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\begin{array}{@{\,}ccc|l@{\,}}
1 & 0 & -1 & a \\
0 & 1 & -1 & a + b \\
0 & 0 & \phantom{-}1 & -\mfrac{1}{2} \, a - \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c
\end{array}
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[left = \empheqlbrack, right =\empheqrbrack]{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\begin{array}{@{\,}ccc|l@{\,}}
1   &   0   &   0   &   \mfrac{1}{2} \, a - \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c \\
0   &   1   &   0   &   \mfrac{1}{2} \, a + \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c \\
0   &   0   &   1   &   -\phantom{-}\mfrac{1}{2} \, a - \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c
\end{array}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with use of `empheq`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{empheq}[left = \empheqlbrack, right =\empheqrbrack]{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\begin{array}{@{\,}ccc|l@{\,}}
1 & 0 & -1 & a \\
0 & 1 & -1 & a + b \\
0 & 0 & \phantom{-}1 & -\mfrac{1}{2} \, a - \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c
\end{array}
\end{empheq}
    \end{minipage}
\quad,\quad
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{empheq}[left = \empheqlbrack, right =\empheqrbrack]{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\begin{array}{@{\,}ccc|l@{\,}}
1   &   0   &   0   &   \mfrac{1}{2} \, a - \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c \\
0   &   1   &   0   &   \mfrac{1}{2} \, a + \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c \\
0   &   0   &   1   &   -\phantom{-}\mfrac{1}{2} \, a - \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c
\end{array}
\end{empheq}
    \end{minipage}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

without use of `empheq` the solution is simpler:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\left[\begin{array}{@{\,}ccr|l@{\,}}
1 & 0 & -1 & a \\
0 & 1 & -1 & a + b \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -\mfrac{1}{2} \, a - \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c
\end{array}\right]
\quad,\quad
\left[\begin{array}{@{\,}ccc|l@{\,}}
1   &   0   &   0   &   \mfrac{1}{2} \, a - \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c \\
0   &   1   &   0   &   \mfrac{1}{2} \, a + \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c \\
0   &   0   &   1   &   -\phantom{-}\mfrac{1}{2} \, a - \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c
\end{array}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both codes are very nice. Thanks.